# How to get FCM Token when user has denied access to allow notifications

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-cloud-messaging

This is my first time working on with firebase due to a requirement by the backend so let me know if you don't understand the question or if it doesn't make any sense. 
What I want to achieve is that I need a `Registration_ID` which is the FCM Token when user register. So this is how I'm implementing it in `AppDelegate.swift` > `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

After that in `AppDelegate.swift` I've added these three functions:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken as Data
    }

    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication,
                     didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
        Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken as Data
    }
```

No the issue is that when it ask for permission of notification and user deny it then how I'll get FCM that I'll send to the backend when user register or login.

Comment: Not possible to get token if the permission is not properly set.

Answer (score 11):

An FCM token is generated regardless of the user's response to the authorization request - if the response takes long enough, the FCM token will be generated before the response is given.

Notifications will not work until the user gives permission but generating the FCM token is not dependent on getting permission.

Please note: I have not found this documented anywhere, but through my own testing.  I have tested on iOS 10.3.1 and 11.0.

The first time the token is generated the `Messaging` delegate's `didRefreshRegistrationToken` is called, I suspect the problem is that you have not set the delegate with

```
Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
```

Answer (score 1):

If user not granting permission, you will not able to send push notification. 3rd party you use cant change this permission (amazon, firebase). For Firebase cloud Messaging Push notification permission is a must.

Comment: I understand that. So what should I do if I still need token? User won't recieve notifications but I still need a callback token you can say.